# 1001: Invalid twitter username or password twitpic

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitpic

I am getting an invalid username or password error when trying to upload to twitpic. I am positive these are correct.

I am using Twitpic.net

```
 Twitpic tp = new Twitpic(data, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterUsername"],        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterPassword"]);
TwitpicResponse resp = tp.UploadAndPost("The Message");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you can actually read the settings from the application configuration? I.e. for example assign the values read from ConfigurationManager to temporary variables and debug/display/print them instead? If the read fails, the returned value will be *null*.

Then, when you can verify that you are indeed sending correct credentials - verify that you have authorized the Twitpic application on your Twitter account?

Additionally, hard-coding the configuration keys is not best practice - use constants or similar approach instead.

Comment: Yes. The correct values are being pulled from The ConfigurationManager. Yes. The credentials are correct. Yes. I have authorized Twitpic. I have tried all variations of username. (ie. @Username, Username, Username@email.com) It still says invalid username and password.